# How do I get the timestamp of a specific file over multiple files within the same folder?

Tags: vba

I'm trying to write a simple script that looks into a folder, finds the specified file, then spits out the timestamp on a cell. That is the easy part which I already have, (using a string & object).

The part where I'm having issues is having this repeat over 400 specific files within a folder of +1,000 files.  All the files are labeled differently, but some may have similarities (AB.xls, AC.xls, AD.xls ; A1.xls, A2.xls, etc). I could go the long way and just rinse and repeat just changing the string name to each specific file, but that would take too long to write.

Is there a short cut to loop this or would I need to add a variable line for the file name to change each time?

Here is a snippet:

```vb
Sub Timecheck() 
    Dim oFS As Object 
    Dim strFilename As String 

    strFilename = "Where the file is located" 
    Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    Sheets("tab").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 3).Value = oFS.GetFile(strFilename).Datelastmodified 
    Set oFS = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: do you have some code we can look at? Do you know the list of file names or are they random?

Comment: Sub Timecheck()
    Dim oFS As Object
    Dim strFilename As String
       
    strFilename = "Where the file is located"

    Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Sheets("tab").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 3).Value = oFS.GetFile(strFilename).Datelastmodified
    
    Set oFS = Nothing
End Sub

Comment: Are the file names in a list? do you know them ahead of time?

Comment: so the file names are located under [C:\Files\], file names for example are: abc.xls, abd.xls, abe.xls, ab1.xls, ab2.xls, ab3.xls, 1a.xls, 2a.xls, 3a.xls. They are not on a list but i've sort of created a list on a new tab thinking i could some how have the script point to the file name under that tab then pull the timestamp per cell...As for knowing ahead of time, yes, they are static file names that are just updated daily

Comment: thanks for updating that snippet, ;P I was looking for how to add that

Comment: No problem, I am not sure you have enough rep yet to edit questions.

Comment: @Pow-Ian, you can edit questions, they just have to be reviewed first. Also, if your edit gets accepted, you gain 2 rep

Comment: @Sean Cheshire - I know. I was implying with my comment that at 1 Reputation Juana did not have enough rep to edit her own question. I really don't know I have never asked a question.

Answer (score 0):

To loop thought a folder:

```
Sub timecheck()
Dim FSO As Object
Dim FLD As Object
Dim fil As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim strFolder As String
i = 1

strFolder = "C:\Your Folder Name"

'Create the filesystem object
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get a reference to the folder you want to search
Set FLD = FSO.GetFolder(strFolder)

'loop through the folder and get the file names
For Each fil In FLD.Files
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) = fil.Name ' Filename in column A
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2) = fil.datelastmodified ' Date in column B
    i = i + 1
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Sean, but i'm too new to completely understand your shortened response. Do you mind explaining a bit? I assumed id have to dim strfolder, fso and fld, but Im not too sure what to do with Fil...

Comment: `dim` them all as `Objects`. fil is the equivalent to `oFS.GetFile(strFilename)` in your original code. use `fil.Datelastmodified` for each file. I will expand the code to explain

Answer (score 0):

If the names of the files are on another sheet you need to create another function that will iterate through that range of cells.

Once you have that function in place have it call this function:

```
Sub Timecheck(byval aCell as object,byval X as integer,Y as integer) 
    Dim oFS As Object 
    Dim strFilename As String 
    strFilename = aCell.Text 
    Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    Sheets("tab").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Cells(X,Y).Value = oFS.GetFile(strFilename).Datelastmodified 
    Set oFS = Nothing
End Sub
```

where X and Y are the coordinates of the cell you want to put the data in. You call it by passing in the cell in the range that you have grabbed from the other sheet.

Alternately if you do not want to have to traverse a range then put each file name in a single cell on the new sheet and delimit it with a character that won't show up in the name. Then take that and break it into the file names.

Good luck.

EDIT:

If you wanted to iterate through the items in a delimited list inside a cell, then once you have the cell text in an object:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.80).aspx

with an input of `'filename1.xls^filename2.xls^filename3.xls'`

call once you have the cell object that contains the file list

```
DoStuff(cellObejct, "^")

Public Sub DoStuff( byval aCell as object, byval specialChar as string)
    Dim ListOfNames as Variant
    Dim intIndex, xCell, yCell as integer

    ListOfNames = Split(aCell.Text,specialChar)

    xCell = 1
    yCell = 1

    For intIndex = LBound(ListOfNames) To UBound(ListOfNames) 
        TimeCheck(ListOfNames(intIndex),xCell,yCell)
        yCell = yCell + 1            
    Next intIndex
End Sub

    Sub Timecheck(byval fName as string,byval X as integer,Y as integer) 
        Dim oFS As Object 
        Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
        Sheets("tab").Activate
        ActiveSheet.Cells(X,Y).Value = oFS.GetFile(fName).Datelastmodified 
        Set oFS = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome, will  try this! Will let you know tomorrow, as work has caught up to my attention. Thanks for the quick responses

Comment: personally I hate iterating ranges, so I would suggest putting all the names in a delimited list and then parsing them.

Comment: looks like finding an iterate function is not easy, for a beginner as myself. would you happen to have a sample? Or would you still suggest using ranges?